# C++ overload resolution between template and non-template functions

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I am confused about c++ overload resolution between template and non-template functions, following is the sample:

```
class Stream {};

struct M
{
    M(float v) {}
};

template <class T>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, T& v) {}

Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, const M& v) {}

int main()
{
    Stream stream;
    int a = 1;

    stream << a; // sample 1
    stream << a * a; // sample 2

    return;
}
```

Here, sample 1 calls the template function. Sample 2 provides an `int&&` type parameter, which can implicitly cast to `const M&`, calls the non-template one, rather then the template one with `T = const int`.

What happen in overload resolution with sample 2 ?

Comment: The const is adding to the things to think about here...

Answer (score 5):

This really doesn't have anything to do with templates.  In

```
stream << a * a;
```

`a * a` materializes an rvalue.  Since your template function takes a `T&` it cannot bind to the temporary so it is discarded as a viable overload.

That leaves you with a user defined conversion to a `M` and

```
Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, const M& v)
```

as the only viable overload.

---

If you change your template to use a forwarding reference like

```
template <class T>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, T&& v)
```

then that will be called in both cases as you will get an exact match.  Do note that you should constrain `T` using SFINAE otherwise this overload will be a match for piratically everything.

Additionally you could use

```
template <class T>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, const T& v)
```

Comment: I can use `operator<< <const int>(stream, a * a);` to call the template one. But `T` cannot be deduced to `const int` implicitly?

Comment: @stanleyerror When you use that then you transform the function to take a `const int&`.  When the compiler tries to deduce the type it gets an `int&&` and `T&` cannot bind to that,

Comment: so if I want the template one to be used with both lvalue and rvalue, I should define the parameter with 'T&&' ?

Comment: @stanleyerror That you as I just added to my answer you could also take a `const T&`

Comment: what's the difference between 'const T&' and 'T&&' here

Comment: @stanleyerror `T&&` gives you a forwarding reference and lets you move the object in the function if you want.  `const T&` on the other hand won't let you move from it because it is `const`.  Most likely for you there wont be any difference for what you want to do though.

Comment: @stanleyerror Read [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).

Answer (score 2):

The template one takes parameter by `T&`, i.e. lvalue-reference to non-const. `a * a` is an rvalue, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const (BTW it could be bound to lvalue-reference to const or rvalue-reference). Then the template one won't be considered.

Answer (score 2):

When used with an lvalue, template is a better match, because it doesn't require calling conversion from `int` to `M`.

However, since non-const lvalue references can't bind to rvalues (which is yield by multiplication) this overload can't be used, so the compiler falls back to the conversion.